# What's the difference between single что and reduplicated что что?

Tags: выбор-слова

At times, I've heard native Russian speakers say что что, instead of single что. For example,

> (I say something that is incomprehensible to a waitress.)

> Что-что?

Is there any difference between что-что and just что? I feel like this is usually used by young women, while men and older women don't say it that much. I also feel like there are other such words (relatively short words) that are often reduplicated, but I'm not sure. Are there perhaps indeed such words, and why are they reduplicated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interrogative words are indeed sometimes reduplicated in Russian.

1. When someone has misheard something or doesn't believe what they've heard, similar to English "come again?"

   > - И если получится, то надо будет ехать в Словакию. ― Куда-куда?.. ― В Словакию, за границу.
   > - Он чётко изложил свою просьбу ― рекомендация в партию! ― Что-что? ― не понял Игорь Васильевич.
   > - Не может быть! Где, где ты увидела? ― Вот, видишь, кольцо одно и второе.
2. To rhetorically emphasize that the answer is obvious. This is similar to English "what else", "you know what", "I'll tell you what" etc. As in English, in this case, the interrogative word is uttered with a declarative intonation.

   > - ― А сама она где? ― Где-где? На окопах
   > - ― Просто интересно было бы знать, где он сейчас. ― Где-где… У неё, где же ещё!
   > - ― Когда это? ― Когда, когда! Прошлым летом.
3. As an [epizeuxis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epizeuxis) (a rhetorical device to emphasize the emotionality or rhetoricity of a question), similar to English "where, oh, where":

   > - Куда, куда вы удалились // Весны моей златые дни?
   > - Зачем, зачем на белом свете // Есть безответная любовь?
4. In a statement, to underline the fact that it's especially true for the subject in question. It's similar to English "of all", like in "of all people", "of all places"; or "if anything".

   > - Казалось бы, уж где-где, а в космическом пространстве пустого места сколько угодно. // Say what you will about any other place, but if there's one thing not lacking in outer space, that's an abundance of empty space.
   > - Уж чего-чего, а воздуха в университетских кампусах хватает. // If there's one thing university campuses have a lot of, it's air.
   > - —  Уж что-что, — говорю, — а вязать я умею. // "If there's one thing I can do", say I, "it's knitting."

Comment: Thank you for the answer and while I understood the functionality of replicated interrogative words, I still don't understand the difference between the single and double interrogative. In this case, I think #1 is applied, but doesn't just что also mean the same?

Comment: @Blaszard: in case 1, it does

Comment: The first usage should be familiar to English speakers who have heard someone say "what what?"

Comment: @CocoPop: in usage 2, they are not questions. "Where is he? You know where, at his mom's". Or "Where is he? At his mom's, where else".

Comment: @Quassnoi: Ah, ok. Got it)) Great response, by the way.

Comment: @Obie2.0: I believe in English you only use "what what" if the second one is a quote. Like in "What?" "What «what»? You heard me"

Comment: No, some people say "What what?" to emphasize their surprise, just like in Russian. The stress is different than in the case you mention: what WHAT  versus WHAT what?

Comment: @Obie2.0: never heard it but maybe some do

Comment: @Quassnoi there is a song of the same name that South Park even did a spoof of.

Comment: @DanM: is "what-what?" (or "where-where?", or "who-who?") an idiomatic way to ask a question synonymous to "I didn't hear you, what (who, where) was that again?" Does it have this meaning in the song?

Comment: @Quassnoi I'm not native to judge whether it's idiomatic or not, but that's how I've seen it used, yes. I also don't think I've encountered such pattern used for anything other than "what" (although I wouldn't be surprised if someone used it like this somewhere). There is also this interesting data point (and links in the comments):https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14369/is-wot-wot-or-what-what-an-authentic-british-expression-if-its-supposed-to/

Answer (score 3):

Singular "что?" is neutral, whereas reduplicated "что-что?" is used in this situation specifically to express disbelief, surprise, misunderstanding or to clear up something misheard. I'd say it shows an escalation of attention.